# Is it insecure to use the following iptable rule for NAT?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking, pptpd

I want to setup a VPN server for personal use, so I follow the blog article [1], and it work like a charm.

The only thing I am wondering is if the iptable's rule secure, e.g.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And I have only one public interface `eth0`, are there any risk in using the rule above?

From other place, I see other alternatives of iptable rules, e.g.

1.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

2.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o ppp+ -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

3.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**So, is my original rule secure?**

Thanks.

[1] http://blog.riobard.com/2011/11/12/pptp-vpn-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

You're using PPTP, so it's already insecure.

As for the masquerade rule, that's required to implement NAT, and you wouldn't be able to access public Internet addresses without it.

Comment: Hi, thanks first. I have updated the alternatives and I wonder if they are needed. My current one is working, but just want to know if there is any risk. Thanks